# position:absolute not working with java mail html message

Tags: html, jakarta-mail

I have written the below code

```
            MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");

        // first part  (the html)
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        String htmlText = 
"<img src=\"cid:image\"\\>\n"+
  "<div style=\"position:absolute; left: 150px; top: 298px; width: 248px;\">hello</div>\n"+
  "<div style=\"position:absolute; left: 176px; top: 349px; width: 225px;\">hello</div>\n"+
    "<div style=\"position:absolute; left: 185px; top: 401px; width: 216px;\">hello</div>\n"+
    "<div style=\"position:absolute; left: 167px; top: 514px; width: 232px;\">hello</div>\n";
        messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlText, "text/html");

        // add it
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // second part (the image)
        messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource fds = new FileDataSource("D://a1.jpg");
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
        messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID","<image>");

        // add it
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    // put everything together
        msg.setContent(multipart);
        bus.sendMessage(msg, address);
```

Everything's working fine and the email is being delivered as well, the only problem is that the `div` elements are supposed to be above the image..but in the recieved e mail the position:absolute part of the e mail is omitted..

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't use `position: absolute`, You better use tables in your emails, it will look better, also, try to create a `<table />` with `background-image` as your `cid:image` and layout your `div`s with table cells

Comment: I tried that...but strangely enough the `cid:image` doesn't work with the `background-image` attribute...